# xmlhttp.send doesn't work on specific server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The following script works on my own server, but after I uploaded it to my webhost, it doesn't send the variables to php file. What causes this problem?

(alert box can display the variables, but the php script run with empty vars)

The script:

`function showHQ(str)`

```
{

var hq_kat = document.getElementById('hq_kat').value;
var hq_terulet = document.getElementById('hq_terulet').value;
var hq_rend = document.getElementById('hq_rend').value;
var hq_megj = document.getElementById('hq_megj').value;
var hq_r = document.getElementById('hq_r').value;

if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

var queryString = "?hq_kat=" + hq_kat ;
queryString +=  "&hq_terulet=" + hq_terulet;
queryString +=  "&hq_rend=" + hq_rend;
queryString +=  "&hq_megj=" + hq_megj;
queryString +=  "&hq_r=" + hq_r;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "search.php" + queryString, true);
xmlhttp.send();
//alert(queryString);
}
```

Comment: your queryString values might have invalid charachters, try `"&hq_terulet=" + encodeURI(hq_terulet)` for all your params.

Comment: if your browser javascript console doesn't tell you why, get a new browser..
for FireFox, its in Ctrl+Shift+K   , in Chrome its F12

you should get an error, tell us what that error says..